# Round to nearest 5 with numpy

Tags: python, pandas

```
df
        A
0  503.36
1  509.80
2  612.31
3  614.29
```

I want to round to nearest 5 in a new *B column*, **using numpy** if possible.

Output should be:

```
        A        B
0  503.36   505.00
1  509.80   510.00
2  612.31   610.00
3  614.29   615.00
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you mention `numpy`

```
np.around(df.A.values/5, decimals=0)*5
Out[31]: array([505., 510., 610., 615.])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
df['B'] = df.div(5).round(0) * 5
```

Or as @piRSquared states:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].mul(2).round(-1).div(2)
```

Output:

```
        A      B
0  503.36  505.0
1  509.80  510.0
2  612.31  610.0
3  614.29  615.0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df.assign(B=df.mul(2).round(-1).div(2))

        A      B
0  503.36  505.0
1  509.80  510.0
2  612.31  610.0
3  614.29  615.0
```